# how to close pop up with dynamic code in python

Tags: python, selenium

i'm new at selenium,and low skilled in python.
simply i'm trying to close a popup on this page https://it.ogame.gameforge.com/
it appear left on top of the page
the popup is not a problem,but want to know how i can do to resolve this.

I inspected the element with chrome,and copy/pasted xpath.
Using the code 
`find_element_by_xpath('xpath code').click()`
it works,and popup closes, but if I refresh page and try again with same code, no work anymore, cause a part of code in is dynamic. How can I solve the problem?
I googled for hours but no fix for now.

This is the element

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="MAX_simplepop_8afcd70d('close'); return false;">x</a>
```

the equivalent in xpath is `//*[@id="MAX_8afcd70d"]/div[1]/a`
but the part "MAX_8afcd70d" changes all the time.

this is the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import traceback

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://it.ogame.gameforge.com/')

time.sleep(2)
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="MAX_8afcd70d"]/div[1]/a').click()
except:
     traceback.print_exc()

finally:

    time.sleep(3)
    driver.close()

##driver.find_element_by_link_text('x').click()
##this works
```

the commented code works but is so simple, and I don't think it can work all the time.

only want to know how I can manage dynamic code in a page with selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case, you have unique class name in the element which can be used to find the element easily, without using dynamic element.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="openX_interstitial"]/div[1]/a').click()
```

But incase, you specially want to try handling dynamic path then you can try

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@id, "MAX_")]/div[1]/a')
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[starts-with(@id, "MAX_")]/div[1]/a')
```

Comment: thx mate,your code works too,and is more versatile.why before class or id there is a @? "contains" and "starts with" si python syntax,am i right?

Comment: The character @ is used to get any attribute of the element like class or id. `contains` and `starts-with` are not python but Xpath functions. You can read more about the syntax and functions for Xpath [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256115(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.Hope it should work each time you run.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="openX_interstitial"]/div[1]/a').click()
```

Let me know if this work for you.

Comment: I have taken the class attribute which is static every time rather Id.please accept my code if it works.

Comment: yes.your code works,and i think i have understood how is structured. //div[@class="open..... indicate the line of class,/div[1] indicate first module in class,and /a is line of function in module.

Comment: To accept this you have to click accept button on my code.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is an version with is_displayed() check.

```
// check if popup class is displayed.
popupelement = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'openX_int_closeButton')
if popupelement.is_displayed():
  print "Popup class is displayed";
  // safe-wait to be clickable
  wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
  xbutton = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@id='openXHackFoo']//div[@class='openX_int_closeButton']/a)))
  xbutton.click();
else:
  print "Popup page is not displayed"
```